# How add dropdown menu to bottom of card

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I made a flexbox card using HTML, CSS. I should add a dropdown menu to the bottom of the card below the footer section, which is shown by clicking the button. I tried but can not get a menu of the same width as a card and right position. How can I achive this?

```js
function showMenu() {
  document.getElementById('dropdown').classList.toggle('show');
}
```

```css
.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.card .header {
  display: flex;
  flex: 2;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.card .body {
  display: flex;
  flex: 5;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.card .footer {
  display: flex;
  flex: 2;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  flex: 2;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: none;
  z-index: 999;
  color: #ffffff;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="header">
    Header
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    Body
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <button onclick="showMenu()">Toggle Menu</button>
  </div>
  <ul id="dropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <li>Menu 1</li>
    <li>Menu 2</li>
    <li>Menu 3</li>
    <li>Menu 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I need dropdown menu same size as card and positioned below footer

Comment: Bring that code example in this SO editor please.

Comment: Add negative `bottom: 70px;`

Answer (score 0):

Add `top: 100%`, `box-sizing: border-box` and `margin: 0` to the menu.

```js
function showMenu() {
  document.getElementById('dropdown').classList.toggle('show');
}
```

```css
.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.card .header {
  display: flex;
  flex: 2;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.card .body {
  display: flex;
  flex: 5;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.card .footer {
  display: flex;
  flex: 2;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.dropdown-content {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 2;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: none;
  z-index: 999;
  color: #ffffff;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="header">
    Header
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    Body
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <button onclick="showMenu()">Toggle Menu</button>
  </div>
  <ul id="dropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <li>Menu 1</li>
    <li>Menu 2</li>
    <li>Menu 3</li>
    <li>Menu 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```